# NGINX - Only matching base domain, will not match "www.domain.xyz"

Tags: nginx

I have a basic NGINX configuation as follows:

```
server {
  listen       80;
  server_name  domain1.ca www.domain1.ca domain2.us www.domain2.us;

   location / {
      proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:82;
   }
}
```

For some reason, "domain1.ca" and "domain2.us" are working as expected, but "www.domain1.ca" throws a 404, as does "www.domain2.us".

Any help here?

Comment: Have you checked DNS records?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have anything to do with nginx